# How to concatenate columns from a ContentProvider query?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contentprovider

I have a table that stores doctors in an Android SQLite database. I want to display the doctor's first name, last name, and suffix (MD, DDO, etc) in a ListView. Currently, I do so with the following query:

```
getContentResolver().query(
   DoctorEntry.CONTENT_URI,
   DOCTOR_COLUMNS, // Includes id, first name, last name, and suffix
   null,
   null,
   DoctorEntry.COLUMN_LASTNAME + " ASC, " + DoctorEntry.COLUMN_FIRSTNAME + " ASC");
```

Here is what `DOCTOR_COLUMNS` looks like:

```
private static final String[] DOCTOR_COLUMNS = {
        DoctorEntry.TABLE_NAME + "." + DoctorEntry._ID,
        DoctorEntry.COLUMN_FIRSTNAME,
        DoctorEntry.COLUMN_LASTNAME,
        DoctorEntry.COLUMN_SUFFIX
};
```

And then, in my adapter class I pull all the information and display it like this:

```
String firstName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DoctorEntry.COLUMN_FIRSTNAME));
String lastName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DoctorEntry.COLUMN_LASTNAME));
String suffix = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DoctorEntry.COLUMN_SUFFIX));

viewHolder.mTextView.setText(firstName + " " + lastName + ", " + suffix);
```

How can I adjust the `projection` parameter to concatenate each row so that I could simply say:

```
String fullName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DoctorEntry.FULL_NAME));
```

Essentially, I'm looking for something like MySQL's CONCAT() function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `||` operator to concatenate expressions:

```
private static final String FULL_NAME = 
    DoctorEntry.COLUMN_FIRSTNAME + " || ' ' || "
    + DoctorEntry.COLUMN_LASTNAME + " || ', ' || "
    + DoctorEntry.COLUMN_SUFFIX;
private static final String[] PROJECTION = { /* id column */, FULL_NAME };

...

getContentResolver().query(
    DoctorEntry.CONTENT_URI,
    PROJECTION, // Includes id, first name, last name, and suffix
    null,
    null,
    DoctorEntry.COLUMN_LASTNAME + " ASC, " + DoctorEntry.COLUMN_FIRSTNAME + " ASC");

...

String fullName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(FULL_NAME));
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly! I had found the `||` syntax somewhere, but I wasn't doing a `rawQuery()` so I couldn't figure out how to implement it inside a content provider like this.

Comment: It's worth noting that this might not work depending on the implementation of the ContentProvider. I've written providers that are accessible by third parties and thus we would actually check the projection elements against the allowed projection set for that particular query/URI, and throw an error if something other than those was included.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I'll definitely bear that in mind for the future.